# udp issue in launcher

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is it possible to check if we don't have any connection to server? I had written this code. I know that UDP doesnt have this function but I want to do this in UDP.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Reg : TRegistry;
  odebrany,lgraczy,mgraczy,hostname:string;
begin
  Application.Title:=Caption;
  UDPClient.ReceiveTimeout := 2000;
  UDPClient.Host:=IdIPWatch1.LocalIP;
  UDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(Self);
  UDPClient.Active := True;
  StrList.Lines.Text:= ip;
  StrList.Lines.Text:=StringReplace(StrList.Lines.Text, '.', #13, [rfReplaceAll]);
  Buffer := 'SAMP' + Chr(StrToIntDef(StrList.Lines[0], 100)) + Chr(StrToIntDef(StrList.Lines[1], 100)) + Chr(StrToIntDef(StrList.Lines[2], 100)) + Chr(StrToIntDef(StrList.Lines[3], 100));
  //Port >> 8 + i
  Buffer := Buffer + Chr(port and 255) + Chr((port shr 8) and 255)+ 'i';
  UDPClient.Send(ip,port,Buffer);
  odebrany:=UDPClient.ReceiveString();
  /**/When odebrany take string program crash here!-**---------------------------------------
  if ( Trim(odebrany) = '' ) then
  begin
    ShowMessage(error);
    ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'cmd.exe', '/c taskkill /F /IM launcher.exe /T' , nil, SW_HIDE);
  end;
end;
```

I was trying this but it wont work

```
if ( Trim(odebrany) = '' ) then
begin
  ShowMessage(error);
```

because program stops early.

Comment: There is no "connection" in UDP.  If you don't get a response from the server, then the server is not running, or it is ignoring you, or the network is dropping the packets. If `ReceiveString()` does not receive a response within the `ReceiveTimeout` period, it simply returns a blank string. So what is the actual problem you are having exactly? What kind of UDP server are you querying exactly?

Comment: My question is about theres a function to check thats the string is actually "blank" i want to use it to do "error message about server is not responding". When 
i dont have any "packet return" using ReceiveString() my program is crashing.

Comment: you are already checking for a blank string (you don't need the `Trim()`). What kind of crash exactly? What is the actual error message? Which line of code is raising the error? You need to be more specific. I see nothing in this code that would crash due to a blank string being received, so it has to be in code you haven't shown

Comment: BTW, you are leaking a `TIdUDPClient` object every time `Button4` is clicked. Why are you even calling `TIdUDPClient.Create()` at all in this code? Clearly `UDPClient` is a member of your Form, so are you creating the `TIdUDPClient` at design time? If so, then you shouldn't be creating a new object. If not, then you shouldn't be setting `ReceiveTimeout` and `Host` before you have created the object.

Comment: My program is crashing when odebrany:=UDPClient.ReceiveString(); After this is without any respond :P

Comment: Again, what is the ACTUAL ERROR MESSAGE when it crashes?  It should NOT be crashing when no response is received, it should simply exit with a blank string.

Comment: Theres no any message, just crash form and i need to kill this process by taskmgr.

Comment: A "crash" could mean a lot of different things. What EXACTLY do you consider a "crash" to be? An Exception being raised? If so, what class type is it, and what does its `Message` say? Or do you consider a "crash" to be something else?  Is your Form/app disappearing from memory, perhaps?  You need to be more specific.  We can't help you without DETAILS.  Also, you haven't commented on the mistakes I mentioned in an earlier comment. Did you fix that yet?

Comment: I need to educate more, about udp packets, maybe then i will fix that problem ;] Thanks for any help ! ;3